# How to send nested JSON input to Restful API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest

I want to Post some data to web API using restful client. Json schema is:

```
{
   "contact":{
      "id":123,
      "first_name":"Jimmy",
      "last_name":"Dee",
      "account_id":123,
      "owned_by":123,
      "email_addresses":[
         {
            "id":123,
            "address":"jimmy@jimmydees.com"
         }
      ],
      "phone_numbers":[
         {
            "id":123,
            "number":"123-123-1234",
            "phone_number_type":"Main",
            "extension":"ex 5"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My C# code for this is:

```
// Endpoint: POST /v1/contacts.json?contact={contact parameters}

var client = new RestClient($"https://api.tripleseat.com/v1/contacts.json")
{
 Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(consumerKey, consumerSecret, null, null)
};
string jsonString=JObject.FromObject( new
{
   first_name = "Foo",
   last_name = "foo",
   account_id = 15998446,
   owned_by = 175177,
   email_addresses = new [] { new 
   {
      address = "test@gmail.com" }
   },
   phone_numbers = new[] { new 
       { 
           number = "38239283928" 
       }
   }
 }
}).ToString();
var request = new RestRequest("?contact=", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonString, ParameterType.RequestBody);
RestResponse response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
```

When I run this code the response generated is with status code of 200 is:

```
{
   "contact":{
      "id":21152554,
      "first_name":"Foo",
      "last_name":"foo",
      "account_id":15998446,
      "owned_by":175177,
      "email_addresses":[
         {
            "id":21692948,
            "address":""
         }
      ],
      "phone_numbers":[
         {
            "id":39428416,
            "number":null,
            "phone_number_type":null,
            "extension":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Problem** is the nested objects email_addresses and phone_number have null values. My question is how I can Post these nested objects in my request?

Comment: Your last json doesn't seem to align with your code, in fact I am having trouble understanding what the problem actually is, or if this last json is from a 3rd party service or not

Comment: I'm trying to understand this API. What happens if you try to use in a retry query the received ids for phone_number and email address? Maybe there are separate endpoints for email addresses and phone numbers. And here you can only assign an address and telephone number to a contact.

Comment: The code showing how you generate *request* but problem presumably with *response* ("When I run this code the response generated is with status code of 200"). There is no way to know why the *response* contains any fields at all without knowing server side code for that method.

Comment: The problem is when I Post data to server the nested object i.e email_addresses and phone_numbers are null